# pseudo-Anosovs with given action on homology

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

It is well-known that the Mapping Class Group of a closed surface of genus $g$ surjects onto $Sp(2g, \mathbb{Z})$ (see, for example the Farb-Margalit book). However, I was wondering if there is a simple proof that the set of pseudo-Anosov elements in MCG surjects onto $Sp(2g, \mathbb{Z})$ (and also a reference for where this might have been stated first) -- I can construct a somewhat sophisticated proof, but this should be easier.

Comment: I assume you mean "surjects onto $Sp(2g,\mathbb{Z))$"?

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, fixed!

Comment: In Lemma 2.5, Darren Long proves that any normal subgroup of the mapping class group contains a pseudo-Anosov. http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0305004100063957  You want to show that a coset of a normal subgroup contains a pseudo-Anosov. One might be able to prove this using a modification of his techniques, which use the action on PML (and might hold in this more general context).

Answer (score 5):

Here's an outline of a proof. Consider a pseudo-Anosov mapping class $\phi$ such that the infinite cyclic group $C = \langle \phi \rangle$ is malnormal. Using the methods of Ivanov and/or McCarthy one can show that for any mapping class $\psi \not\in C$, the mapping class $\psi \phi^k$ is pseudo-Anosov for sufficiently large $k$. Now apply this with $\phi$ in the Torelli group and $\psi$ representing any element of $SP(2g,\mathbb{Z})$.

**Some details added later:**

*First part:* There is a simple direct construction of a pseudo-Anosov in the Torelli group: use Penner's recipe, which says that if $c,d$ are a filling pair of curves then $\tau_c \tau_d^{-1}$ is pseudo-Anosov. Take $c,d$ to be separating. The malnormality requirement can also be obtained by choosing $c,d$ so that no mapping class fixes both $c,d$ nor interchanges them.

*Second part:* Since $\psi \not\in C$ then (as in Sam's answer) $\psi$ fixes neither the attracting nor repelling measured geodesic laminations of $\phi$, and neither does it interchange them; thie follows from the assumption that $C$ is malnormal. Now pick a tiny compact neighborhood $K$ of the attracting lamination of $\phi$, so tiny that $\psi(K)$ does not contain the repelling lamination. Pick a high power $\phi^k$ so that $\phi^k(\psi(K))$ is in the interior of $K$ and so that $\phi^k\psi$ is contracting on $K$; this is possible because, in projective train track coordinates, $\phi$ is contracting near its attracting lamination. By this means (and working similarly with the inverse) one shows that $\phi^k\psi$ has north-south dynamics (and hence so does its conjugate $\psi\phi^k$). Finally, no reducible mapping class has north south dynamics, so $\psi\phi^k$ is pseudo-Anosov.

Comment: This approach was my first thought, but this seems pretty heavy duty (why is there such a mapping class in Torelli? What are these methods of McCarthy and Ivanov?)

Comment: To answer your second question, I am referring to the methods of proof of the Tits alternative for mapping class groups.

Comment: As pointed out in my comment, Darren Long has shown that any normal subgroup contains a pseudo-Anosov, so being in Torelli is irrelevant.

Comment: I am being dense, I know, but this (expanded) argument seems to show that $\phi^k \psi$ maps any neighborhood of $\lambda^+$ to its. Does this mean that its attracting lamination is the same as that of $\phi?$ This seems implausible.

Comment: No, but it does mean that as $k \to \infty$, the attracting lamination of $\phi^k \psi$ approaches that of $\phi$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $f$ is a pseudo-Anosov and let $\lambda^\pm$ be its stable and unstable laminations.  Suppose that $g$ is any mapping class with the following property: $g(\lambda^+) \neq \lambda^-$.  Then, for all sufficiently large $n$, the composition $f^n g$ is also pseudo-Anosov.  This is proved using the north-south dynamics of $f$.

Now, as in Mosher's answer, choose $f$ in Torelli and let $g$ be a lift of the desired element of $Sp$.  If needed, compose $g$ with a bounding pair map to arrange the side-condition.  We are done.

Added later: Here are some of the details of the dynamical argument. I've edited this several times to try and make it correct.  Full disclosure - I first heard this from Yair Minsky.

Pick $U$, a small neighborhood of $\lambda^+$, chosen so that $\lambda^-$ is not contained in $g(U)$.  I'll also want $f|U$ to be strictly contracting. Using north-south dynamics, there is an $m^+ > 0$ so that for all $n > m^+$ we have $f^{m^+} g(U) \subset U$.  The contracting property implies that the map $f^n g$ has a unique fixed point in $U$.

On the other hand, pick a small neighborhood $V$ of $g^{-1}(\lambda^-)$, so that $\lambda^+$ is not in $V$.  Also, we require $f^{-1}|g(V)$ to be strictly contracting  There is a power $m^- > 0$ so that for all $n > m^-$ we have $V \subset f^n g(V)$.  Deduce that the map $f^n g$ has a unique fixed point in $V$.

We place one more restriction on $n$.  We need $f^n g(V^c)$ to be contained in $U$. 
I now claim that $h = f^n g$ has no other fixed points, and so is pseudo-Anosov.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "north-south dynamics"?

Comment: A map $h$ of a topological space $X$ acts with north-south dynamics if $h$ has a pair of distinct fixed points $a$ and $b$ with the following property.  For any neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ containing $a$ and $b$, respectively (but not containing $b$ and $a$, respectively) there is a positive integer $n$ so that $f^n(X - V) \subset U$ and $f^{-n}(X - U) \subset V$.  The point $a$ is called "attracting" and the point $b$ is called "repelling".  The roles of these points are played by $\lambda^{\pm}$ in the case of a pseudo-Anosov map.

Comment: I am aware of the definition, but why does it work here?

Comment: This part of my answer will look similar to the second part of Lee's addition.  I'll write out my version to see how our side-conditions compare.